# Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' error when i run react with docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, tailwind-css

I am creating a project that will use tailwind. I've dockerized my react project, but I get `Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'`. If I run it without docker it'll work without an error.

Here's my react docker-compose part:

```yaml
reactclient:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
      - /frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    stdin_open: true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY package.json .
RUN npm i

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I've got default `tailwind.config.js` and `post-css.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

I've tried to remove and install node_modules.